# C++ CLI GUI Event Handeling

Tags: c++, events, click, c++-cli, mouse

I am working on a c++ CLI application and am having some difficulty with events. I am wondering if I can get events to fire while the mouse button is clicked. For example, I am wanting to check whether or not the mouse has moved to the next square over only if they have the mouse clicked in. Meaning if they click on square 1 they should be able to hold that click and move the square 2 and my program recognize this.

I have run a number of different events on the mouse, including the "Click" event, but the neither the hover, mouse enter, or mouse down event get triggered while the button is pressed. The "MouseClick" event, which does the same. I tried using just the mouseDown event, but this does not let another mouseDown event, mouse enter, or hover event fire.

Short of checking mouse position I do not know what I can do. I would like to not have to do mouse position checking.

If anyone has any ideas, they would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What platform are you developing for?

Comment: Windows, I thought CLI was only for windows development.

Comment: You tagged your question with "CLI" which is for "Command Line Interface" not C++/CLI.

Comment: Doh. Sorry about that thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearly you'll want to pay attention to the MouseMove event so you can see the mouse moving into another square.  Roughly:

```
    void panel1_MouseMove(Object^ sender, MouseEventArgs^ e) {
        if ((e->Button & System::Windows::Forms::MouseButtons::Left) == 
                         System::Windows::Forms::MouseButtons::Left) {
            int square = MapPosToSquare(e->Location);
            if (square != currentSquare) {
                currentSquare = square;
                OnSquareClicked(currentSquare);
            }
        }
    }
```

If these "squares" are actually controls then you have a different problem.  You have to set the control's Capture property to false in the MouseDown event handler so it doesn't capture the mouse.

Comment: Well I wanted to try to avoid mouse positioning and I have more than two squares, I have about 16. Wanted to see if it was possible to do it from the default events for the windows form controls.

Comment: Does this capture property have to be set programatically? and does this simply release the mouse to be detected be other event handelers?

Comment: Thank you after investigating, this is exactly what I was looking for.